# Convert gpencil to curve, python, crash

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves, grease-pencil

I'm not well versed in scripting and I'm trying to write a script that involves converting grease pencil to curve, I have discovered that the operator

```
bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(type='CURVE', use_timing_data=True)
```

needs the 3D view context to work, however if i set the correct context Blender crashes without any crash log

i have tried these two options

```
import bpy

area = bpy.context.area
old_type = area.type
area.type = 'VIEW_3D'

bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(type='CURVE', use_timing_data=True)

area.type = old_type
```

and

```
    import bpy

    win      = bpy.context.window
    scr      = win.screen
    areas3d  = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
    region   = [region for region in areas3d[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']

    override = {'window':win,
                'screen':scr,
                'area'  :areas3d[0],
                'region':region,
                'scene' :bpy.context.scene,
                }               

bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(override, type='CURVE', use_timing_data=True)
```

How to explan the crashing and is there maybe a different approach for creating curve from grease pencil?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The custom context has an invalid region set, which results in the region data `rv3d` pointer being `NULL` in `gp_camera_view_subrect()` ([`gpencil_convert.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/gpencil/gpencil_convert.c)).
In your custom context `region` is set to `[bpy.data.screens['Scripting']...Region]`. Instead of a list it should be a single `bpy_struct`. This can be fixed by modifying your `override` dictionary:

```
override = {'window': win,
            'screen': scr,
            'area'  : areas3d[0],
            'region': region[0],
            'scene' : bpy.context.scene}
```

Alternatively you could copy the current context and modify the `area` and `region`.

```
import bpy


context = bpy.context.copy()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                context['area'] = area
                context['region'] = region
                break
        break

bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(context, type='CURVE', use_timing_data=True)
```